# How to reinstall 1wire support

Tags: raspbian, 1-wire

While trying to configure my Pi0 for read-only mode I deleted my /sys/bus/w1 folder. Now the 1wire bus is not working anymore. How can I reinstall the module?

Comment: Please take (in case you haven't yet) the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Changing the title to **Solved** is not how things are handled here. Please just accept the answer that solves the issue.

Comment: Now that you mention it it makes so much sense. I will do that tomorrow because I cannot accept my own answer yet.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to wait some time to do so. Welcome to site and have fun with the Pi!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working again!

I was following [this guide](https://kofler.info/raspbian-lite-fuer-den-read-only-betrieb/) (I know it's written in German but you get the point) and configured the /sys/bus folder as a temporary file system. I didn't know that the whole /sys folder already is a temporary folder managed by the kernel. After removing the entry and rebooting from /etc/fstab everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 2):

Add the line `dtoverlay=w1-gpio` to the file `/boot/config.txt` and then reboot.

See `/boot/overlays/README` for details.

Comment: Thanks, but I already had that line in the config.txt and everything was working before I tried to configure the Pi for read-only mode. However, the problem is solved now!